# how to judge CORDOVA environment in it's html script?

Tags: html, cordova, phonegap

I am making a composite-website supporting both web-browser & cordova-app. I want to add "cordova.js" script-element dynamic by javascript in *.html page. but how can I know I am in cordova-app environment?

(background: making a composite-website supporting both web-browser & cordova-app.)

I make cordova "config.xml" as follow:

```
<widget ...>
    ...
    <content src="http://192.168.0.102:3000/index.html" /><!--my website-->
    ...
</widget>
```

And in my website page "index.html" I write:

```
<script>
$(function(){
    if (???? CONDITION ????) {
        var scriptcordova = document.createElement('script');
        scriptcordova.async = false;
        scriptcordova.src = 'cordova.js';
        document.head.appendChild(scriptcordova);
    }
});
</script>
```

Page without condition is running well in cordova. But WHAT CONDITION to use?

Answer (score 1):

I compare the whole window-var of browser and cordova. found window._cordovaNative={} in cordova's window. so condition can be:

```
if ('_cordovaNative' in window) { // in cordova environment }
```